# Add custom scrollbar for Tabs in react-toolbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, scrollbar, react-toolbox

I am using `Tabs` componnent of [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/tabs). Everything is going well except when the text of the `Tabs`menu is too long and is overlapped by other part as the image below:
[image: tab is overlapped]

By adding directly to `nav` the properties `overflow-x: auto`, I can scroll normally to the last tab but is there any way to style the horizontal scrollbar inside of `Tabs` component used other React components like [react-custom-scrollbar](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) or should I write a js function to handle the scrollbar?

In the second option, how should I implement the function?